# forChild and forRoot usage with router module

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am little bit confused on **forRoot** child and **forChild** behaviour, when working with RouterModule.

If I use RouterModule.forChild(routes) inside a routing module, and import same in **app.module.ts**, and then if I try to use **router-outlet** inside **app.component.ts**, it throws error.

As per definition :

`forChild` creates a module that contains all the directives and the given routes, but does not include the router service.

router service is for browser location detection, but why it is not able to find router-outlet directive as definition clearly state it will contain all directives.

But if same thing is done inside a feature module, it works fine.

Sorry for not posting code, as it will be lengthy.

Comment: Are you importing only the RouterModule.forChild(routes) not forRoot()? What is the error you get by Angular?

Comment: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!, I just wanted to get deep concept so I tried doing RouterModule.forChild(routes), normally in main module you should do RouterModule.forRoot.

Answer (score 3):

`RouterModule.forRoot()` needs to be there in the `AppModule`. It is the one that instantiates the router services. All other modules will use the `RouterModule.forChild([])` for handling the routing.

You should have only one `forRoot` usage in an app.

Comment: forRoot will instantiate router service that I agree, but if you see the angular router git hub code.  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_module.ts (Line no 94, it is saying it will provide directives) , so I am more concerned, why it is not able to find router-outlet directive.

Comment: Its because the provider `ChildrenOutletContexts` is a part of `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`. This is a dependency only when you use `forRoot`. not when you use `forChild`. The `router-outlet` needs an instance of `ChildrenOutletContexts`, but since it is not provided by `forChild`, you will get the error.

Comment: Then how the same thing work for Feature Module?, is it taking from App Modules

Comment: It shouldn't work anywhere, until a `forRoot` is used. Please reproduce it on stackblitz if you get it working.

Comment: If you are using a forRoot in AppModule, all the instances are available for the feature module to use.

Answer (score 2):

Check [router source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.7/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L158-L198).

`forChild` registers routes, whereas `forRoot` registers routes and configures/initializes router itself